# Adding rows to a dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose to have the following dataset

```
df=data.frame(country=c(rep("POL",4),rep("UK",4)),year=c(rep(2000:2003,2)),
              index=c(1.5,1.5,1.55,1.6,1.78,1.8,1.8,2))
```

The desired outcome is:

```
   country year index
1      POL 2000  1.50
2      POL 2001  1.50
3      POL 2002  1.55
4      POL 2003  1.60
5      POL 2004    NA
6      POL 2005    NA
7      POL 2006    NA
8       UK 2000  1.78
9       UK 2001  1.80
10      UK 2002  1.80
11      UK 2003  2.00
12      UK 2004    NA
13      UK 2005    NA
```

I tried to construct the following vectors:

```
v1=rep("POL",3)             
v2=rep(2004:2006)
v3=rep(NA,3)
v4=rep("UK",2)
V5=rep(2004:2005)
v6=rep(NA,2)
```

The idea is to use v1,v2,v3 as column vectors, which add to df, just after the fifth observation. Then, doing the same for v4,v5,v6 just after the eleventh observation. I don't know how to proceed.
Of course, this is an example, since I'm dealing with a large dataset and choosing after which observation to put my column vectors is crucial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for `rbind` (with name-correction), `dplyr::bind_rows`, or `data.table::rbindlist`:

```r
rbind(
  df,
  data.frame(country=v1, year=v2, index=v3),
  data.frame(country=v4, year=V5, index=v6)
)
#    country year index
# 1      POL 2000  1.50
# 2      POL 2001  1.50
# 3      POL 2002  1.55
# 4      POL 2003  1.60
# 5       UK 2000  1.78
# 6       UK 2001  1.80
# 7       UK 2002  1.80
# 8       UK 2003  2.00
# 9      POL 2004    NA
# 10     POL 2005    NA
# 11     POL 2006    NA
# 12      UK 2004    NA
# 13      UK 2005    NA
```

Similarly:

```r
dplyr::bind_rows(df, data.frame(country=v1, year=v2, index=v3), data.frame(country=v4, year=V5, index=v6))
data.table::rbindlist(list(df, data.frame(country=v1, year=v2, index=v3), data.frame(country=v4, year=V5, index=v6)))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried something very similar but then I had problems sorting data by country and by year. Let's stay with your code. I run: 
```
df2=rbind(df, data.frame(country=v1, year=v2, index=v3), data.frame(country=v4, year=V5, index=v6))

df3 = df2[order(df2$country, df2$year), ]
``` The unpleasant thing is that POL 2004, for instance, enters as the ninth observation in lieu of the fifth. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Don't confuse row _names_ with row numbers. In R, a row name is always a string; when first created and when nothing else is defined, R effectively uses `as.character(1:nrow(x))` as the row names, emphasis on the string nature. From there, when you reorder it, the row names themselves are preserved, so you now know that what _was_ named `"9"` is now in row 5. Many functions ignore row names unless explicitly used. If it really bugs you, do `rownames(df3) <- NULL` to "reset" them to sequencing strings. Does that resolve it for you?